# How to assign different individual public IP addresses to computers on same network

Tags: networking, router, ip

My account on a public forum has been disabled because of 'multiple aliases' (no further details). Having read the forum rules I think this means there are several different accounts logging on to the forum from the same IP addresses.

I haven't (knowingly) done this, so my guess is that there are other users on my network (i.e. my company network) logging on to the same forum. From what I've read (correct me if I'm wrong) our network router will be using the same public IP address for all the computers on the network.

Is there anyway to get around this? to give my computer it's own unique public IP address that can't be mistaken for any other?

UPDATE - one of the issues with being banned is that I can't log on to contact an administrator / moderator!

Comment: _"the same public IP address for all the computers on the network."_ or one from the available bunch. You can use a proxy for that instance/browser  or a VPN (there are addons for i.e. for firefox or chrome to allow it in a fluid way). You can even write to that forum administrator and explain that xxx.yyy.zzz.ttt is your company IP and there are many computer that exit with this ip (but do not aspect so much from the mail...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### XY problem

Sorry to say, yours seems to be an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).
You need only to connect your computer to that forum without being banned, not to assign different public IPs to computer connected to the same local network. And this can be even easier! `:-)`

So, let's proceed step by step.

1. You should investigate better on the cause of the banning. It can be even simply because another user starts to massively upvote your comments.
2. Write to the adminstrator of the forum and ask for clarifications, explain that you may connect via a wide company network, and that it is probable there will be other users with the same issue.
3. Only in that case (banned bacause of multiple logs from the same ip) try to see if the forum administrator can add your IP to some white list, or if your NET administrator can do something to add your IP to the list used by the forum.

   - (Tl;dr)
     I mean that many home providers (e.g.) buy a bunch of IPs, a good number, and each time that an home user connects, the provider selects (at random or not) one free exit IP to assigns to this client... knowing that, there are lists of IP ranges known to be part of those *provider reserves*, and those lists are seldom used as *white-list* from the forums. Note that your company is big enough, the it can act as an home provider...
4. In the meanwhile, you may think to add some add-ons to your browser in order to use some [proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) or [VPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network).
5. You can use something like teamviewer and connect to your computer at home... then connect from that computer to the forum.
6. Last resort you can ask to your company network administrator if you have more external IP and to use a specific one... always if you were allowed to read that forum from your working computer.